# Import files, using interrupts - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, import

I have a laravel app. I use a cronjob which runs every 4 hours, and imports csv files and saves in the database.

I have limited times (300 sec max execution time, 60 sec cpu time). The import script should import a lot of csv files (400+).

Is there a way to interrupt before the time runs out and call the import script again? Or how could I solve this so the files can be imported safely?

Comment: You use a job scheduler for this. So you put all "import jobs" into a queue (typically database based) and then execute single import jobs, one after another. That makes the work load fine grained. Now you can implement your cron job to have only controlling character. It is triggered every x minutes and checks if there are any jobs to be processed. If so, then it starts an import job, if not it exits. The important part is to separate control and import jobs.

Comment: you can use third party queue service like amazon or iron.io for better result

Comment: thank you for both comments.
@arkascha: I would try to go on with your suggestion. Could you point me to the right direction? I will have an import job class, which I push to the queue with the filename to be imported, for example. Do I need to take care about if the same file being submitted to the queue? When should I push the jobs to the queue? And one more thing: how can I run the jobs in the queue? Run a Daemon Queue Worker? (Sorry, I'm new to laravel, went through the docs, but still had these questions)

Comment: Sounds all fine, looks like you _are_ on the right track ;-)

Comment: You should add some form of file system based locking in case you are afraid that the same file might get registered for import twice.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution if you want to guarantee the process is completed is to use non-overlapping task scheduling. You can read all about it in the documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps

It's in fact still a cronjob, but Laravel internally will make sure only one process runs at a time. As such you can still (for example) schedule it to run every minute, so that it immediately restarts after it ends or .. in your situation schedule it to run every 4 hours without the risk of restarting when the previous is not yet done.